# Content overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have some content that is overlapping some other content. Here is the HTML and CSS:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="image_block">
  <a href="#"><img src="src.png" alt="July 4th" usemap="#Map" border="0" /></a>
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area class="declaration " shape="poly" coords="109,255" href="#" />
      <area class="constitution" shape="poly" coords="145,253" href="#" />
    </map>  
</div>
<p style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</p>

<!-- This content is coming over the image -->

<p><a href="/home"><img class="center" style="width:185px;" src="src.png" />
</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="copyright"><p>Copyright &copy; 2012</p></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.image_block    {
   width: 710px;
   height: 500px;
}

.image_block a  {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.image_block img    { 
  /* Nothing Specified */

}
```

How do I keep content from overlapping?

Note: I do not mind changing the CSS as long as the image stays centered on the bottom of the screen as the CSS here provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing with this

```
.image_block a  {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `position: absolute;` it makes no consideration of the other content in your web page, but only the position in the screen. if you want to get rid of overlapping, you will have to follow relative positioning and use `float` attribute of CSS.

i.e.

```
.image_block a  {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That messes up the alignment of the image which must be aligned center of the page at the bottom of the page.

Comment: to make it center:
{
 width: widthoftheimage px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
you can try to calculate the pixels for tho bottom of the page and try something like
 {margin-top: pixelsfromtop px;}